# How do I fix this speed varible writing back to file?

Tags: python

I've been writing a program, I've run into an error. My current code is:

```
import tkinter as tk
speed = 80
def onKeyPress(event, value):
    global speed 
    text.delete("%s-1c" % 'insert', 'insert')
    text.insert('end', 'Current Speed: %s\n\n' % (speed, ))
    with open("speed.txt", "r+") as p:
        speed = p.read()
        speed = int(speed)
    speed = min(max(speed+value, 0), 100)
    with open("speed.txt", "r+") as p:
        p.writelines(str(speed))
    print(speed)
    if speed == 100:
        text.insert('end', 'You have reached the speed limit')
    if speed == 0:
        text.insert('end', 'You can not go any slower')



speed = 80

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')
text = tk.Text(root, background='black', foreground='white', font=('Comic Sans MS', 12))
text.pack()

# Individual key bindings
root.bind('<KeyPress-w>', lambda e: onKeyPress(e, 1)) 
root.bind('<KeyPress-s>', lambda e: onKeyPress(e, -1)) #

root.mainloop()
```

I believe `speed = min(...)` is causing the error. However do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem (I guess it's the problem you're having) is that you are trying to overwrite the content of file `speed.txt`, however, the value you are writing contains fewer characters than already contained in the file.

This can lead to unexpected values winding up in your file, e.g. if the file contains

```
10
```

Consider what happens if you try to decrement the value by 1 (user hit the `s` key):

```
with open('speed.txt', 'r+') as p:
    speed = int(p.read())

speed -= 1    # speed is now 9

with open("speed.txt", "r+") as p:
    p.writelines(str(speed))
```

`speed.txt` now contains:

```
90
```

Instead of decreasing the speed to 9, it has actually been increased to 90! If the speed was already 100 and you tried to decrement it, you would end up with 990 in the file.

This is because opening the file with mode `r+` opens the file for reading and writing and positions the file pointer at the beginning of the file. A write will only overwrite the first *n* characters where *n* is the length of the data written. Hence you can get the sort of corruption shown above.

You can fix this by opening the file with mode `'w'` for the _second__ `open()`. This will completely overwrite the file. And you don't need to use `writelines()`, just use `write()`.